# Regex: match a link that begins with http/https or just site.com/... but NOT with prefix?

Tags: php, regex

I need to match links, but only those who don't begin with the string [image:x] where x is the link itself.

I need this in a preg_replace so that only links that fit will be changed, here is an example:

> "a dog once ate my book `http://mysite.com/dog.jpg` and I had to go to
>   the store `https://www.mysite.com/images/store.png` and buy a new iPad
>   `apple.com/iPad/iPadMini.jpg`  And there it was fun
>   [`image:http://apple.com/iPad/images/iPads.com`]"

would result as

> "a dog once ate my book `[image:http://mysite.com/dog.jpg]` and I had to go to
>   the store `[image:https://www.mysite.com/images/store.png]` and buy a new iPad
>   `[image:apple.com/iPad/iPadMini.jpg]`  And there it was fun
>   [`image:http://apple.com/iPad/images/iPads.com`]"

Notice the last link, as for now I get it doubled (the link is still picked up by preg_replace). like here (not the desired effect, I need it untouched):

> `...[image:apple.com/iPad/iPadMini.jpg]`  And there it was fun
>   [`image:[image:http://apple.com/iPad/images/iPads.com]]`"

Here's my preg_replace as for now:

```
preg_replace('~(https?://)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\S*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif)~','[[image:$0]]',$text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

We don't want it to start with '[image:'. We also don't want to start in the middle of a word. this is prevented using `\b`. If the string starts with `http://` it should be included in the match, so don't match after `http://` or `https://`.

```
preg_replace('~(?<!\[image:)(?<!http://)(?<!https://)(?<!\w\.)(https?://)?\b[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\S*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif)~','[image:$0]',$text);
```

Check this [PHP fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/85z-027)

*Note: that also won't replace a string with the final `]` missing, like `[image:example.com`.*

Comment: as in here: `[image:http://[image:icons.iconarchive.com/icons/ergosign/free-environment/256/sunflower-icon.png]]`

Comment: May I just ask how can you read this in human language? (I am not familiar with this syntax - the beginning)

Comment: @Ted Please use [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/), which can explain, build, debug and test regular expressions. (costs €30)